# How to zip two arrays of paired tuples?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have thrown many darts at trying to get this to compile. I have two collections that are created with something like:

```
let ab:[(Int, Int)] = someCollection.map { thing in 
    return (a, b)
}
let cd:[(Int, Int)] = someCollection.map { thing in 
    return (c, d)
}
```

I want to combine them and cannot find the correct syntax to give me a working compile:

```
let merged:[(Int, Int)] = zip(ab, cd).map { ab:(Int, Int), cd:(Int, Int) in
    return ab[1] > cd[1] ? ab : cd
}
```

The parameter list for the closure is the problem. I have tried `((a, b), (c, d)) in ...` and numerous other variations, with and without the `:Int` hints. I always get either:

```
Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
```

or

```
Closure tuple parameter does not support destructuring
```

Is there no way to zip two lists of paired tuples?

Comment: `let merged = zip(ab, cd).map { $0 > $1 ? $0 : $1 }`

Comment: Tuples members are indexed with dot notation, `t.0`, `t.1`, ..., not with subscript notation `a[0]`, `a[1]`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let merged = zip(ab, cd).map { (x, y) in
    return x.1 > y.1 ? x : y
}
```

Comment: Sigh. I tried like 12 things. I was trying too hard in this case I guess. I thought I needed some specificity, and the more I threw at it, the worse it got.